# Create object from multiple lines in .txt file

Tags: java

My problem:

I have txt file with that structure:

```
20:00   Norwich Res-Milton K.   
2.45
3.30
2.45 
20:30   Everton Res-Blackpool   
2.24
3.25
2.73
```

What i want is to read text file, and create objects from data inside. One object that i need is ie.(fields of one object ) :

```
    20:00   Norwich Res-Milton K. (String)
    2.45 (double)
    3.30 (double)
    2.45 (double)
...
```

My method to read data from txt:

```
public ArrayList<Match> getMatches(){
    try{
        File file = new File("matches.txt");
        FileReader readerF = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(readerF);

        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
               //here i dont know what to do 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Do You have any tips/tricks how to do that?
Thanks a lot for some answer

EDIT:

My Match class:

```
    public class Match {

        private String matchName;
        private double course1;
        private double courseX;
        private double courseY;

        public Match(String matchName, double course1, double courseX, double courseY){
            this.matchName=matchName;
            this.course1=course1;
            this.courseX=courseX;
            this.courseY=courseY;

    }

}
```

Comment: grab each line, if the line contains ":" you know you are at the beginning of a new object. Take that line and use it to contruct a new object along with the next 3 lines for it's other variables.

Comment: one possibility is: `if (line.contains(":")) String tempStr = line; else double tempDbl = Double.parseDouble(line.trim());` Notes: this depends on if file structure, ensure all cases are handled. Also the temp variables would need to be printed/stored because they'll loose scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I'm assuming the input file is valid so you might need to handle exceptions otherwise):

```
     public ArrayList<Match> getMatches(){
        try{
            File file = new File("matches.txt");
            FileReader readerF = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(readerF);

            String line = null;
            String matchName = null;
            double course1;
            double courseX;
            double courseY;
            ArrayList<Match> matches = new ArrayList<>();
            int count = 0;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                   if (count%4 == 3) {
                       Match match = new Match(line, course1, courseX, courseY);
                       matches.add(match);
                   } else if (count%4 == 2) {
                       courseY = Double.parseDouble(line);
                   } else if (count%4 == 1) {
                       courseX = Double.parseDouble(line);
                   } else {
                       course1 = Double.parseDouble(line);
                   }
                   count++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
        }
        return matches;
    }
```

Comment: i needed to replace the first if instructions with the else instructions, but anyway:
It works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  The logic for `"//here i dont know what to do"`  needs to be something like this:

1. Is this a line that starts a new match?
2. If yes:

   1. parse the line to extract components
   2. create new match record
   3. make it the current match record
3. If no:

   1. Is there a current match record?  If no, then ERROR.
   2. parse the line as a number
   3. add the new number (whaterever it means) to the current match record.